# Yodlee only showed 2 accounts but there are actually 4

Tags: yodlee

I added one Citizens Bank account into yodlee. Yodlee showed there are only 2 accounts inside. But actually there are 4, which made the customer can't get the transaction details from the other 2 accounts

What is the reason for this? and how could I solve it?

Thanks.
Yu

Answer (score 0):

Yodlee would require more information to debug this.

1)are you testing on the developer.yodlee.com?
if no then
   a)The SOAP/REST URL used
   b)The cobrandId  you are using
2)The itemId of the account linked.

Comment: The url I am using is: https://consolidatedsdk.yodlee.com/yodsoap/services. The cobranded is: 5910008380. The itemID is: 16453676.

Comment: The issue is fixed and now you will be seeing all your accounts. If you run into any such issues in future it's advisable to use the Yodlee customer care tool to report it.